# how can i get exact opengl cordinates from touch in android opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm using the opengl ES 2.0 Example in the android developers site.

I'm getting the screen cordinates of using the touch events in android.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    float x = e.getX();
    float y = e.getY();
}
```

Can anyone help me in converting them into openGL world coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

edit:
You're right, default openGL coordinates system has its center in the center of the screen but you can easily change that. I don't really like the approach shown at android developer site. Here's an example of setting up the scene to make the coordinates start at left bottom corner.

```
private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16]; // this is the matrix you will send to your shader
private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    Matrix.orthoM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, 0f, width, 0.0f, height, 0, 1);
    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, 1, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
}
```

Note that with this approach you set coordinates of your figures in your screen space which is much more convenient than <-1, 1> range in my opinion.

And now you can use this code to get the coordinates of your touch:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touch_x = event.getRawX();
    float touch_y = yourScreenHeight - event.getRawY();
}
```

Comment: the center of the openGL display coordinates is the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

put this in the onSurfaceChanged function this is will chang the coordinate system like android uses:

```
      float [] ortho=
    {
    2f/width,   0f,         0f, 0f,
    0f,        -2f/height,  0f, 0f,
    0f,         0f,         0f, 0f,
    -1f,         1f,         0f, 1f
    };
float ratio = width / height;
//public static float[] m2dProjectionMatrix = new float[16]; 
System.arraycopy(ortho, 0, Render.m2dProjectionMatrix, 0,ortho.length);

GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
Render.width=width;
Render.height=height;
 //public static float[] mModelMatrix= new float[16]; 
Matrix.setIdentityM(Render.mModelMatrix, 0);
```

you'll need this 2 float matrix in you vertex shader m2dProjectionMatrix and mModelMatrix and you need this line too in it

```
 gl_Position = (m2dProjectionMatrix ) *mModelMatrix * vec4(a_Position.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
```

a_Position.xy is the coordinate you touch if you want to move the origo you can do that by modifying the mModelMatrix like this:

```
    //mMoveMatrix is an array like the other two
    // positionX and positionY is the coordinates to move the origo
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mMoveMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mMoveMatrix, 0, positionX, positionY, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMoveMatrix, 0, Render.mModelMatrix, 0, mMoveMatrix, 0);
   // use mMoveMatrix insted of mModelMatrix
```

I hope I didn't  screw up and it'll work